# find consecutive nonzero values

Tags: matlab, find, return-value, chain

I am trying to write a simple MATLAB program that will find the first chain (more than 70) of consecutive nonzero values and return the starting value of that consecutive chain.

I am working with movement data from a joystick and there are a few thousand rows of data with a mix of zeros and nonzero values before the actual trial begins (coming from subjects slightly moving the joystick before the trial actually started).

I need to get rid of these rows before I can start analyzing the movement from the trials.

I am sure this is a relatively simple thing to do so I was hoping someone could offer insight.
Thank you in advance

EDIT: Here's what I tried:

```
s = zeros(size(x1)); 

for i=2:length(x1) 
    if(x1(i-1) ~= 0) 
        s(i) = 1 + s(i-1); 
    end 
end 

display(S);
```

for a vector x1 which has a max chain of 72 but I dont know how to find the max chain and return its first value, so I know where to trim. I also really don't think this is the best strategy, since the max chain in my data will be tens of thousands of values.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  What have you tried?

Comment: s = zeros(size(x1));
for i=2:length(x1)
    if(x1(i-1)~=0)
        s(i) = 1 + s(i-1);
    end
end
display(S);     for a vector x1 which has a max chain of 72 but I dont know how to find the max chain and return its first value, so i know where to trim. Thank you

Comment: no problem.  I edited your post to remove the thanks, though.  It's not "appropriate" in a question.

Comment: Awesome, that code works perfectly. But just so I can understand it, how is the first if statement and counter exclusively counting for a consecutive chain? I had tried something similar to this and the counter reached over 70 before it got to the longest chain, simply because it was counting all the nonzero numbers in the vector, without them being consecutive.

Comment: Just so you know, this comment should be made as a comment under my answer, not the main question.  Sorry for being pedantic...I'm about to edit my answer with an additional explanation.  Check there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use an auxiliary vector to keep track of the index:

```
for i = 1:length(x)
    if x(i) ~= 0
            count = count + 1;
    elseif count >= 70
            lastIndex = i;
            break;
    else
            count = 0;
    end

    if count == 70
           index = i - 69;
    end
end
```

To remove all of the elements in the chain from `x`, you can simply do:

```
x = x([lastIndex + 1:end]);
```

EDIT (based off comment):
The reason that the way you did it didn't work was because you didn't reset the counter when you ran into a 0, that's what the:

```
else
   count = 0;
```

is for; it resets the process, if you will.
For some more clarity, in your original code, this would be reflected by:

```
  if x1(i-1) ~= 0 
        s(i) = 1 + s(i-1); 
  else
        s(i) = 0;
  end
```

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with your research.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is generic for any chain size. It finds the longest chain in a vector `x1` and retrieves the first element of that chain `val`.

First we'll use [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) to label connected components, For example:

```
s=bwlabel(x1);
```

Then we can use [`tabulate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html) to get a frequency table of `s`, and find the first element of the biggest connected component:

```
t=tabulate(s);
[C,I]=max(t(:,2));
val=x1(find(s==t(I,1),1, 'first'));
```

This should work for the case you have one distinct maximal size chain. What happens for the case if you have more than one chain that has maximal lengths? (you can still use my code with slight modifications...)